# How to Use Melt to Tidy Dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

dt = {'Ind': {0: 'Ind1',
1: 'Ind2',
2: 'Ind3',
3: 'Ind4',
4: 'Ind5',
5: 'Ind6',
6: 'Ind7',
7: 'Ind8',
8: 'Ind9',
9: 'Ind10',
10: 'Ind1',
11: 'Ind2',
12: 'Ind3',
13: 'Ind4',
14: 'Ind5',
15: 'Ind6',
16: 'Ind7',
17: 'Ind8',
18: 'Ind9',
19: 'Ind10'},
'Treatment': {0: 'Treat',
1: 'Treat',
2: 'Treat',
3: 'Treat',
4: 'Treat',
5: 'Treat',
6: 'Treat',
7: 'Treat',
8: 'Treat',
9: 'Treat',
10: 'Cont',
11: 'Cont',
12: 'Cont',
13: 'Cont',
14: 'Cont',
15: 'Cont',
16: 'Cont',
17: 'Cont',
18: 'Cont',
19: 'Cont'},
'value': {0: 4.5,
1: 8.3,
2: 6.2,
3: 4.2,
4: 7.1,
5: 7.5,
6: 7.9,
7: 5.1,
8: 5.8,
9: 6.0,
10: 11.3,
11: 11.6,
12: 13.3,
13: 12.2,
14: 13.4,
15: 11.7,
16: 12.1,
17: 12.0,
18: 14.0,
19: 13.8}}

mydt = pd.DataFrame(dt, columns = ['Ind', 'Treatment', 'value')

How can I tidy up my dataframe to make it look like?

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkx9d.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```